# Join two select statement results with join statements

Tags: sql, join

I want to combine two result statement that i have made like this..

**Statement 1:**

```
SELECT Ta_Kontrak.No_Kontrak, Ta_Kontrak.Tgl_Kontrak, Ta_Kontrak.Nilai, Ta_Kontrak.Nm_Perusahaan, Ta_Kontrak.Kd_Prog as prog, Ta_Kontrak.Kd_Keg as keg,
       Sum(Ta_SPP_Rinc.Nilai)as SPP from Ta_kontrak left join Ta_SPP_kontrak on Ta_Kontrak.No_Kontrak = Ta_SPP_kontrak.No_Kontrak 
       left join Ta_SPP_Rinc on Ta_SPP_Kontrak.No_SPP = Ta_SPP_Rinc.No_SPP
Group By Ta_Kontrak.No_Kontrak, Ta_Kontrak.Tgl_Kontrak,Ta_Kontrak.Nilai, Ta_Kontrak.Nm_Perusahaan, Ta_Kontrak.Kd_Prog, Ta_Kontrak.Kd_keg
ORDER BY Ta_Kontrak.Kd_Prog, Ta_Kontrak.Kd_keg asc
```

**Statement 2:**

```
SELECT Ta_Kontrak.No_Kontrak, Ta_Kontrak.Tgl_Kontrak, Ta_Kontrak.Nilai, Ta_Kontrak.Nm_Perusahaan, Ta_Kontrak.Kd_Prog as prog, Ta_Kontrak.Kd_Keg as keg,
       Sum(Ta_SPP_Rinc.Nilai)as SP2D  from Ta_kontrak   join Ta_SPP_kontrak on Ta_Kontrak.No_Kontrak = Ta_SPP_kontrak.No_Kontrak 
          Join Ta_SPM on Ta_SPP_Kontrak.No_SPP = Ta_SPM.No_SPP   Join Ta_SPP_Rinc on Ta_SPP_Rinc.No_SPP = Ta_SPM.No_SPP
          Join Ta_SP2D on Ta_SPM.No_SPM = Ta_SP2D.No_SPM 
Group By Ta_Kontrak.No_Kontrak, Ta_Kontrak.Tgl_Kontrak,Ta_Kontrak.Nilai, Ta_Kontrak.Nm_Perusahaan,Ta_Kontrak.Kd_Prog, Ta_Kontrak.Kd_keg
ORDER BY Ta_Kontrak.Kd_Prog, Ta_Kontrak.Kd_keg asc
```

Please help me..

Comment: How should the result look like. Read [ask] and improve your question

Comment: I don't see the purpose of the extra join in the second query.

Comment: it should be a line with these coloumns :No_Kontrak, Tgl_Kontrak, Nilai, Nm_perusahaan, Prog, Keg, SPP, SP2D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine Two result sets Try union or union all

Comment: I tried used union and union all, but the results not look like i want.. coloumn SPP and SP2D come into one coloumn not separated